# Cygwin+Memcached+libevent-как закомпилить?

Tags: windows, memcached, cygwin, c++

Всем привет.

Решил сегодня закомпилить memcached 1.4.1x под Cygwin. Сначала столкнулся с тем, что memcached не копилируется с gcc, который поставляется в комплекте с дистрибутивом Cygwin. Закомпилил ради memcached gcc 4.6.0. Но, что-то никак не даётся мне memcached.
Для компиляции memcached требуется libevent. Его сырцы забрал с оф. сайта libevent, закомпилил, в результате получил в /usr/local файлы в папках. Среди папок есть и папка include с файлом event.h и другими заголовочными файлами, а в папке lib есть файл libevent.a и другие файлы libevent. Но, при выполнении ./configure в папке memcached
выходит ругань, что не видит libevent и предлагает скачать libevent с офф. сайта.
Пробовал и

```
./configure --with-libevent=/usr/local/lib
./configure --with-libevent=/usr/local/
```

и с флагами парился-всё равно libevent memcached не видит... Если кто знает, как решить данный вопрос, подскажите, пожалуйста, а то не хочется на половине пути останавливаться...

Comment: А так простенькая программы (хотя бы из configure) с libevent компилится/собирается? Что нибудь типа

       gcc -I/usr/local/include test.c -L/usr/local/lib -levent

Comment: Ага, компилируется, но есть одно но:
gcc -I/usr/local/include test.c -L/usr/local/lib -levent
не компилится, т.к. заголовочные файлы libevent лежат не в /usr/local/include, а в /usr/local/include/event2
gcc -I/usr/local/include/event2 test.c -L/usr/local/lib -levent
работает отлично.

Comment: Ну не знаю. Ставить libevent из дистрибутива неохота. А вот в пакете      libevent-dev 1.4.13-stable-1 инклюд-файлы:

       /usr/include/evdns.h
       /usr/include/event-config.h
       /usr/include/event.h
       /usr/include/evhttp.h
       /usr/include/evrpc.h
       /usr/include/evutil.h

Подозреваю, что в event2 хедеры от другого пакета

Comment: Вообщем, удалил я этот кусок конфига.
Теперь валится на проверке  pthread_create... no
Код, который идёт на проверке  pthread_create вручную компилится нормально, но в конфиге валится.
Удалил из конфига и проверку  pthread_create, создались соответствующие файлы конфигурации.
Пытаюсь закомпилить через make валится, зараза

Comment: gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pe
dantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcach
ed-memcached.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-memcached.Tpo -c -o memcached-memcach
ed.o `test -f 'memcached.c' || echo './'`memcached.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -DNDEBUG   -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -Werror -pe
dantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -MT memcach
ed-hash.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/memcached-hash.Tpo -c -o memcached-hash.o `test -f ' hash.c' || echo './'`hash.c gcc: unrecognized option -pthrea

Comment: Нормально компилится тот же код
<code>
/* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
   Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
   builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
char pthread_create();

int
main() {
    return pthread_create();
    ;
    return 0;
}
</code>
командой
g++.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o main.cpp

Comment: Чего-то я не понимаю. Ну Чилентано в комедии так авто ремонтировал, а вот поступать так ради установки библиотеки, которая нужна будет для работы -- нафиг-нафиг. Программы и так обычно работают не очень хорошо, чтобы их ещё ломиком на место ставить. Подозреваю, что Вы поставили libevent-2.x. Попробуйте libevent-1.4.x

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пытаетесь собрать memcached под cygwin, видимо, вам необходимо запустить memcached под windows. Это гораздо проще сделать, если взять готовый дистрибутив, благо такие существуют и отлично работают. [Загрузка](http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win32-1.4.4-14.zip).

Comment: Версию от northscale.com я видел.
Сначала да, я вопрос решил с помощью аналогичной сборки.
Но, войдя в азарт решил ручками закомпилить - не люблю, когда у меня что-то не получается.